# How to filter the main array in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, filter, aggregation

Imagine an array coming to a step in aggregation pipeline like below:

```
[{
  name: "John",
  address: { zip: 1111 }
},{
  name: "Doe",
  address: { zip: 2222 }
}]
```

So, now if I want to filter all the objects which are address.zip: 2222, how that aggregation stage would look like? I'm a bit confused with the documentation because it only shows the way to implement the [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in a subarray to filter the items in the subarray itself.

I know that this can be achieved if I just used the find() function but here the issue is up to the previous stage, things are dynamically generated so I need to find a way to filter this in the aggregation itself.

Any help regarding this is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what is your test data and expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$match` ?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      address: {
        zip: 2222
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dxc7VqG0Obl)

Answer (score 1):

Would be

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "address.zip": 2222
    }
  }
])
```

`$filter` is used to remove elements from an Array, e.g.

```
{ $filter: { input: [ 1,2,3,4,5,6 ], cond: {$lt: ["$$this", 4] } } } => [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Hi again, I need a bit of clarification. I can use something like this: 
{ $eq : [ temperature , 'pve' ] }
to compare two outside variables inside the $fitler. but we can't do that with $match as we cant use operators like $eq inside $match. is there anyway I can compare outside variable values inside the $match?

Comment: Do you mean `{ $eq : [ "$temperature" , 'pve' ] }`?

Comment: Nope, temperature as a js variable.

Comment: Then `{ $eq : [ temperature , "$pve" ] }`? It's fairly difficult to guess without any sample input data.